# SVN Error - Left locally modified or unversioned files

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a main line of development and a branch.  On the main line, a new directory has been added to SVN, with some files in it.  It also contains directories called bin and obj, which are in my global ignore pattern in TortoiseSVN.  Whenever I try to do a Switch on my working copy from the trunk to the branch, I get the error "Left locally modified or unversioned files".  I have tried doing a diff before the switch, and nothing shows up as modified.  After the error message, I can manually delete the directory, do a cleanup, and then try the switch again and it completes successfully.  Switching in the other direction doesn't cause any problems.  What's going on here?

Comment: Have you tried putting those directories into SVN's global ignore pattern? (Settings->General->Subversion configuration file)

Answer (score 1):

Ignore patterns are only evaluated for new files. So if some file are already under version control (like your bin/ and obj/ directories) your ignore patterns are meaningless. You have them locally and they exist in repository, too. And svn can't decide which are the 'correct' ones.

Solution: Either remove bin/ and obj/ from version control or ignore the contents of the two directories. The latter is the way I prefer.

Comment: The bin and obj directories are not in the repository.

Comment: As I understand you they exist in repository in trunk/ but not the branch (...It also contains directories called bin and obj...) . This is the only way I currently can think of how I could explain your problem.

Comment: No, there's a directory for the project that was added.  Call it subproj, inside my main project.  It only exists on the trunk.  So /trunk/mainproj/subproj exists in SVN, and contains some files and directories.  obj and bin aren't in the repository. /branch/mybranch/mainproj exists, but doesn't contain subproj.

Comment: Well, the new directory can't be the source of your problem, nor I have an idea what else it could be. Sorry :(